# Windows 8.1 Grouped Taskbar Button Selection

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

I recently installed the Windows 8.1 update and it made a minor change to the way grouped taskbar buttons are navigated.

When using the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> shortcut to select a grouped item on the taskbar, it is possible to cycle through the windows in the group by repeatedly pressing <kbd>#</kbd> (corresponding to the position on the taskbar) and holding down <kbd>Windows</kbd>.

Prior to the update, simply letting go of <kbd>Windows</kbd> once the desired item within the group was found would cause the window to be come active, but now it requires an extra keypress (<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> seems to work) to confirm the selection.

Does anyone know how to get the old behavior back (window selection upon release of <kbd>Windows</kbd>)?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through your tabs.  It is much quicker and a lot less headache than using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> option.  In addition, I have windows 8.1 and I do not need to press anything when using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> option.